# How to estimate the cost of flooding events in a given year?

Tags: probability

I have a cost associated to three flooding events with different return period: 5 years, 25 years and 100 years. The probability that an event with return period 5 years happens is `pr(5) = 1/0.5 = 0.2`. Same for the others: `pr(25)=1/25=0.04` and `pr(100)=1/100=0.01`.

To each event I have associated a damage cost: `C(5) = 1000`, `C(25)=1500` and `C(100)=2000`.

I would like to estimate the annual cost  given the three events. Should I consider the three events independent and do something like the following?

`C = pr(5) * C(5) + pr(25) * C(25) + pr(100) * C(100)`

Comment: Even if the events are *not* independent, expected values are additive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linearity of expectations ALWAYS holds. What you need to do additionally in calculating the expected costs is to take the present value of these expected costs. For example: if you end up spending $100$ units of currency $5$ years from now, then at an average rate of interest of $10\%$, that money is worth $\frac{100}{1.1^5}$ to you today.

So your cost formula needs to be updated as:

$$E(\text{Present Value of Cost}) = \frac{P(5) C(5)}{(1+r)^5} +\frac{P(10) C(10)}{(1+r)^{10}} + \frac{P(15) C(15)} {(1+r)^{15}}$$

Where $r$ is your assumed constant rate of interest over the years.

Comment: a question: in this case low is `r` higher is the cost. Am I right? should not it be `(1-r)^5`

Comment: No. That is not correct.

Comment: so I do not understand why for higher rate of interest the price decrease

Comment: If you had to draw a loan from the bank to pay, say $X$, for a future event,let's say $t$ years from now at an interest rate $r$, that results in the cost $X$, how much loan should you apply for? Let's say you apply for an amount $Y$ and we want $X$ after $t$ years. So what do you get as the value for $Y$?